# Why do we write [0] after get_or_create in model_name.object.get_or_create() in django

Tags: python, django

A function in Faker script to add data in my model Department.
    
`department = ['I.T.','C.S.E','M.E.','E.C.']
def add_dept():
    d = Department.objects.get_or_create(dept_name=random.choice(depatment))[0]`

Answer (score 5):

`get_or_create()` is a queryset method, which returns a tuple `(d, created)`. where `d` is the model instance and `created` is `boolean` flag which tells us if the object is created or not.

so by getting the first index like this

```
Department.objects.get_or_create(dept_name=random.choice(depatment))[0]
```

You are actually doing `(d, created)[0]` which always returns the object. A better way to do this is to use underscore (`_`) to ignore created flag, like this:

```
d, _ = Department.objects.get_or_create(dept_name=random.choice(depatment))
```

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 1):

This is because `get_or_create` returns a tuple and you're usually only interested in the gotten or created `object` (first element) and not the boolean indicating if the object was just created (second element).

From the [documentation on `get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

> Returns a tuple of `(object, created)`, where `object` is the retrieved or created object and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

Though you can also use the syntax:

```py
def add_dept():
    d, _ = Department.objects.get_or_create(dept_name=random.choice(depatment))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) return a 2-tuple where the first item is the `Department` object that is constructed or obtained, and the second is a boolean (`True` or `False`) that is `True` if the object was constructed, as specified in the documentation:

> Returns a tuple of `(object, created)`, where `object` is the retrieved or created object and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

By adding `[0]`, you thus obtain the first item of the 2-tuple: the department, and thus discard the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're calling returns a list or a tuple. In either case, the [0] simply extracts the first element from the result, and throws any remaining results away.